# ruby - copy a jar from linux to windows server

Tags: ruby, shell

We are having a linux build server and the build scripts are written in ruby. All the jars are deployed on linux servers only and are generally copied to the application servers using **ssh**.

There is a new service which needs to be deployed on a windows server. ***Is there a way to copy and configure the jar deployment from the linux machine to the windows server.***

Using ruby / shell scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already using SSH in your build script I would think the easiest thing to do would be to install an SSH server on the Windows box. You can use [sshd via Cygwin](http://www.noah.org/ssh/cygwin-sshd.html) or opt for a commercial product like WinSSHD (I'm sure there are numerous other free or paid products out there).

Once you have that running you can more than likely reuse most of the existing script relating to moving files around and use a gem like Win32Utils to do any windows specific tasks.

Comment: Sounds good. Have setup an openssh server via cygwin. Will let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Okay, had some issues with OpenSSH on Cygwin... files were getting copied, but I was unable to locate them on my windows machine. Finally resorted to standalone OpenSSH installation and worked like a charm!